# Should i use let or const in vue 3 ref variables?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, coding-style, vue-composition-api

I am creating a new Vue 3 project and i saw many people online declaring refs like this.
`const myVariable = ref(false)`
Why are we using **const** all of a sudden in Vue 3? 
 I get that *refs* wrap them in some way to make them editable but i still don't get why not declaring them like this: 
`let myVariable = ref(false)`
I know it may sound a foolish question for Vue 3 devs but i cannot understand the **reason** behind changing values to **constants**.

During the meanwhile i am using the const declaration in composition API but i'd like to acknowledgwe the reason behind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's preferences but the argument why `const` is used is when the value is not changing e.g:

```
const name = 'John';

// Shouldn't work.
name = 'Bill';
```

With `ref()`, you don't replace the variable but the property

```
const name = ref('John');

name.current = 'Bill';
```

---

Here's how `eslint` explains it:

> If a variable is never reassigned, using the `const` declaration is better.
>
> `const` declaration tells readers, “this variable is never reassigned,” reducing cognitive load and improving maintainability.

Docs (at the time of writing): https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/prefer-const

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Do you know when people should use **let** in combination with **ref()**?

Comment: i never experienced one so i really can't tell. if you want to use `let` then it shouldn't cause any problem. you can try re-assigning the value and see what happens. i believe it won't react to the change because Vue track changes of object property, not variable. that's just not possible at all in javascript even. See https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#how-reactivity-works-in-vue